# Android Studio Zxing Scanner, how to redirect to web page after qr code scan automatically (Webview)

Tags: android, webview, qr-code, zxing

I would like redirect to web page after QR code scan (Android Studio Zxing Scanner), after scan code when I press buttontoast, it is redirect to an URL, but I want to redirect without button press automatically alter scan.

No idea where to place the URL for redirect:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/d2.aspx?name=" + MainActivity.resulttextview.getText());
```

Using (Webview)

#### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    resulttextview = findViewById(R.id.barcodetextview);
    scanbutton = findViewById(R.id.buttonscan);
    buttontoast = findViewById(R.id.buttontoast);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    scanbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanCodeActivity.class));

        }
    });

    buttontoast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, resulttextview.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com/d2.aspx?name=" + MainActivity.resulttextview.getText());

        }
    });
```

#### ScanCodeActivity.java:

```
public class ScanCodeActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA=0;

    ZXingScannerView scannerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        MainActivity.resulttextview.setText(result.getText());

        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }
}



enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the url directly when you scan a Qr code, add your logic in the handle result method like this:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

This will open link in any browser installed on phone. If you want to specifically open a link in webview inside your application, call startActivityForResult in MainActivity, set result in ScanCodeActivity after you detect the URL and handle the sent result in OnActivityResult in MainActivity. I hope this might help you.